# IPython import failure and python sys.path in general

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython

I'm following this [post](http://isbullsh.it/2012/04/Embed-ipython-in-virtualenv/) to make one ipython rule all the virtualenvs.

From what I understand, the main idea of the post is that when in a virtualenv, ipython can not find its modules.

```
(a-virtualenv)me@pc:~$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
ImportError: No module named IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp
```

To work around this, I add this to my /usr/bin/ipython

```
import sys
if "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")
```

This trick works for Balthazar. But in my case, I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .frontend.terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/embed.py", line 37, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 38, in <module>
    from IPython.core.completer import IPCompleter
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 84, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import generics
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/generics.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.external.simplegeneric import generic
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external/simplegeneric/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _simplegeneric import *
ImportError: No module named _simplegeneric
```

I thought maybe I should add `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external` to `sys.path` in `/usr/bin/ipython` as well. What I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/loader.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.path import filefind, get_ipython_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 24, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import _find_cmd, system, getoutput, arg_split
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import text
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/text.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.external.path import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

This error occurred on line 43 of `IPython/__init__py`, but the previous one occurred on line 46.

1. How can I make ipython work with virtualenv?
2. How can adding `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external` to `sys.path` resulting a new error?
3. What should I read to get a better understanding of python import path?

Thanks!

PS:
normal IPython sys.path

```
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Comment: can you post what you see if you run `import sys; print sys.path` in your *normal* python? (i.e. the one you installed IPython against)

Comment: Now after '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7' added, ipython seems work.

Comment: well it seems like you've resolved your problem (basically, by checking your path and then figuring out what you actually needed to add).  You should post that as an answer to this question.

Comment: I've had this error when I was in a virtualenv and tried to start ipython, when ipython was installed globally and not in the virtualenv.

Comment: You can still use the globally installed ipython by adding the path mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IPython seems to work now!

Because ipython can not find simplegeneric. I tried to locate simplegeneric and found simplegeneric is in '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7'. After '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7' being added, ipython works fine.

Jeff Tratner's comment really helps!

Comment: I found the following command worked: PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages ipython (this was on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7 inside a virtualenv)

Answer (score 7):

If you install `ipython3` using `apt-get`, you would not face any problems like that.

Instead of `ipython`, you should type `ipython3` on the terminal.

For Python 2 use `ipython2`.

Comment: +1: **ipython2.7 qtconsole** works now... where only **ipython** worked! Thanks for the fixes all the way to jrvidotti (it was a struggle)

Answer (score 4):

Making changes to the path did not help in any way. However running ipython as a super user worked (although I'm not proud of it!)

```
sudo ipython
```

Comment: okay, it solved the problem. But who can officially explain why? o_O

Answer (score 3):

`pip install ipython` instead of `apt-get install ipython`.  The former installs into the virtualenv, the latter installs into your system python packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case the cause of it was that the directory: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages was not added to the path when the virtual environment was created (I would like to know why)

In my case the following in the terminal solved the problem:

```
workon 'your_environment_here'
add2virtualenv /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Note: This assumes you are using virtualenvwrapper

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a package higher up in my customized Python path named "path" that was causing the ImportError from:

```
import IPython.external.path as path
```

See https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3994

Answer (score 0):

I experienced some weirdness in a new ubuntu host, and realized I was getting different behaviors for mkvirtualenv on mac versus the ubuntu. I got past this difference with

```
'mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages mynewenv'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to *upgrade* IPython from 0.13.2 to the currently newest 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Similar `traceback` I experienced with `python 3.5.4` and `pip 10.0.1` after installing `ipython` successfully.

```
line 32, in <module>
from .debugger import TerminalPdb, Pdb
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/debugger.py", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython.core.completer import IPCompleter
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 137, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import generics
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/utils/generics.py", line 8, in <module>
from simplegeneric import generic
ImportError: No module named 'simplegeneric'
```

updating or installing the `simplegeneric` i.e `sudo pip install simplegeneric --upgrade` I get

> Requirement already up-to-date: simplegeneric in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.8.1)

After some initial trial I searched on google/stackoverflow to see if anyone else faced similar problem and found this. And its @zjk answer that helps me to find solution.

**Solutions:**
Found only `egg` folder in the `python3.5` installed package dir. So I removed them and fresh install the `simplegeneric`.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplegeneric-0.8.1-py3.5.egg-info/
sudo pip install simplegeneric
```

after that ipython worked just like charm.

**N.B:** I install the package at the system level that's why `sudo` required.