# Error to launch IPython shell after source install

Tags: python, linux, path, ipython, pythonpath

I have an account in a CentOS server without sudo permission. As a result, I tried to install IPython from source code by `python setup.py prefix=<my home directory>`.

However, I got the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
ImportError: No module named IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp
```

I found a question same to mine: [IPython import failure and python sys.path in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573844/ipython-import-failure-and-python-sys-path-in-general).

I followed the asker's instruction to add the directory of my IPython to the IPython execution file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Terminal-based IPython entry point.
"""
import sys
sys.path.append("./Ipython directory")

from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance

launch_new_instance()
```

However, I got the same error as well. So I want to know how can I launch IPython correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to install with the [`--user`](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme) flag, which should put it on `sys.path` automatically.

```
python setup.py install --user
```

If you need to use `--prefix` for some other reason, then make sure that the directory you add to `sys.path` is the folder *containing* the IPython package, not the IPython directory. It will probably end with 'site-packages'.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the `IPython` source folder into ~/bin/. The execution file of `IPython` can recognize the module in `IPython` and the IPython shell launches successfully.